# Getting error for installation of Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and trying to install it by following a video on youtube.
But I'm getting error and cannot proceed. 
I'm getting this error,

> "Because flutter_tools depends on pubspec_parse 0.1.5 which doesn't
>   match any versions, version solving failed. Error: Unable to 'pub
>   upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)"

Here's what I have done.

```
vim .bash_profile
```

changed the path to `"export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"` (I changed the[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY] to my path, something like "user/name/ ... developer/. Also I press I key to insert them. If you know how to fix it, please let me know. I searched on Google but couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: mac OS catalina